# group by two joined columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (a int);

CREATE TABLE T2 (a int);

SELECT T1.a , T2.a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a=T2.a
GROUP BY T1.a;
```

I get an error from this code:

> Msg 8120 Level 16.
>   Column 'T2.a' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I would have expected this to work because T1.a and T2.a are joined

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Your expectation is wrong.  It is that simple.  Unaggregated columns (expressions) in the `SELECT` need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have expected this to work because T1.a and T2.a are joined

This makes sense, but unfortunately: no. SQL Server sees two different unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`  clause, and wants them in the `GROUP BY` clause too:

```
SELECT T1.a, T2.a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
GROUP BY T1.a, T2.a
```

On the other hand, since *you* are joining on these columns, you also know that both have the same value, so why would you need to output both in the resultset?

```
SELECT T1.a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
GROUP BY T1.a
```

Some databases support the `USING` syntax on joins, which disambiguate the column names when both are the same - but not SQL Server:

```
SELECT a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON USING(a)
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would have expected this to work because T1.a and T2.a are joined

The SQL Standard states that when there is *dependency between columns of the same table*, there's no need to aggregate the dependent ones. For example if you aggregate by the primary key, you don't need to aggregate other columns of the **same** table. However this is not the case, since the `T2.a` is on a different table. Nevertheless, SQL Server does not implement that part of the standard anyway.

Now, with a minor change it works:

```
SELECT T1.a , T2.a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a=T2.a
GROUP BY T1.a , T2.a;
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa10a745d7c2aa47178036c77eb64900).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `t2.a` column in `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
T1.a , T2.a
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.a= T2.a
GROUP BY T1.a, T2.a;
```

It is necessary to add `t2.a` as when SQL Server groups the same rows by `t1.a`, it does not know what column should be chosen for `t2.a`.